# How to put out a polystyrene fire?

Tags: insulation, fire-hazard, fire

I'm planning to use some polystyrene in a project. I will try to avoid all fire hazards, but in case the worst happens is there anything special I should know about how to fight polystyrene fires? Would a fire extinguisher work? Does it depend on the type of extinguisher?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need anything special for that type of fire, like you might grease or electrical. Water would work pretty well as the easiest leg of the three-legged fire stool (heat, fuel, air) to knock out from under polystyrene is heat. Water will also solidify it instantly and prevent spreading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ABC extinguisher would be my choice I carry one on my truck and 2 in my boat. They will put out everything but electrical & magnesium, kill the electrical first then the fire will not be electrical.
Magnesium takes a special chemical in the service it was called purple K .

ABC will put most things out quickly, last week we had a  Fire In a field just after a major power bump.
I was the first one there and with 1 medium fire extinguisher i was able to knock down the circle of about 40’ by using short controlled shots.

Where it started back up I was able to stomp it out, until our fire truck got there and we soaked the entire area down.

Even a small extinguisher can put out a decent sized fire with control. For home or office use I recommend ABC type extinguishers.